# son of obsidian vs2010 bad effect

Tags: visual-studio-2010

everyone! I downloaded son of obsidian from http://studiostyl.es/schemes/son-of-obsidian, and I referred to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/08/13/change-your-visual-studio-color-scheme-vstipenv0034.aspx to install the style on VS2010. Everything is default, but the effect is so bad.

I'm new here, so I don't have enough reputation to post images. Has someone meet this question before? Once I have enough reputation, I will post the image. Please execuse me. Thanks for Malice, I have uploaded the image to a url. I'm sorry that I can't show the url for lack of reputation, but you can find it in the comments below.

Can anyone tell me why the bad effect happened and how to change the effect to the best effect showed on the first website?

A small question, why is the letter of "hello" before "everyone" deleted by the system?

Comment: Does not look like this question belongs here... Probably better to be asked on superuser.com... Or maybe directly from the author of the scheme.

Comment: OK! I will try to concact with the author. In truth, for almost every style on the first website above, I have the bad effect. The compute I use is a desktop, can the question be related to the display device?

Comment: @user2234874: Can you host your image on http://imgur.com/ and post a link to it?

Comment: @Malice: [http://imgur.com/NnXwyVB](http://imgur.com/NnXwyVB) I have uploaded it. As it shows, it's a bad effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit I have never modified my colour scheme by installing a template, I've always just changed the colours manually so the advice below might not be much use.
Here is the template the way it *should* look:
[image: Correct source image]

and here is the way yours looks:
[image: Wonky image]

The colours for the background, keywords, operators and numbers looks the same to me. If you have custom colour values set for Identifiers and Literals then you could try changing them by going to Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors and changing the appropriate item in the Display Items list.

You could also try resetting your colour scheme to the default by going to Tools->Import and Export settings and selecting "Reset all settings". Once your colour scheme is reset, you could change the colours manually or try installing the template again.

Comment: I'm sorry that I said "install the style". It's not true installation. The original meaning of mine is also to go to Tools->Options->Environment to set it, which you can see from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/08/13/change-your-visual-studio-color-scheme-vstipenv0034.aspx). I will try what you said. Once I have a result, I will tell you. Thank you very much!

Comment: It still doesn't work! Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: I have found the reason. The bad effect is caused by the plugin of Visual Assist X. It sets fonts and colors.